# Print drawn lines from RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, richtextbox, gdi+

I have created an application to draw lines in RichTextBox control using RichTextBox.CreateGraphics() method, now i want to print the drawn lines into paper, the problem is in getting the the drawn lines from the richtextbox.

Any help please...

Comment: This isn't going to work. Those lines aren't really there, they're just temporarily drawn on top of the control. That's the limitation of the `CreateGraphics` method. If you minimize the window and then restore it, you'll see that the lines are gone. Same thing if you drag the window off the screen or otherwise force a repaint. You'll need to do it the right way, by subclassing and handling the paint event. Then you can just tell the control to paint itself to a bitmap (`Control.DrawToBitmap`), which you'll output to the printer.

Comment: Thanks for help, is it better to draw on a picturebox than on panel?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you draw on, it matters when your drawing code runs. The drawing code needs to run in response to a Paint event, not arbitrarily when you call `CreateGraphics`. Think of `CreateGraphics` as just giving you a *temporary* way to draw on an object. If you want to *permanently* draw on an object, you need to add your drawing code to its permanent set of drawing instructions.